# How to 'host' a Work Item inside a WinForms application?

Tags: tfs-sdk, tfs-workitem

I've come across a couple applications in the past that run outside VS2010 (or MTM) but display TFS Work Items 100% as they are shown in VS2010 as if there was a way to get the WorkItem including all its controls as a complete 'control' and place it inside my own application.

Does anyone know how to do that? I am currently trying to remember where I saw that, but maybe someone knows what I am talking about and can point me in the right direction TFS client api wise!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls.WorkItemFormControl` class. Doc on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.controls.workitemformcontrol%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

This class has a property `Item` of type `WorkItem`, set the object and you're good to go.
If you want an application that uses it, I made [this one](http://wicreator.codeplex.com/), go get [the sources](http://wicreator.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/71408), it's in the CegWICreator Project in the MainForm.cs file. If I remember correctly (the app is quite old) this control is pretty well used at some different places.

Comment: Thanks! Stumbled upon the class late last night, too, but having a  project with an actual sample implementation certainly helps.

Comment: If I remember there are few things that won't act as you expect with this class and it's not the MSDN (where the doc is pretty poor) that will help you, so a code sample may help indeed.